# Add padding between input text

Tags: html, css

I want to add a text (calculator format) to an input field containing following data:

- a digit
- a sign (x, -, +, /)
- a digit

How to add padding between those elements in one input field, so I could have:

```
[digit][30px gap][sign][10px gap][2nd digit]
```

Gaps between digits can be customized either.

Adding simple padding to the input doesn't help... ( https://jsfiddle.net/gzuv6Lr4/ shows it)

Any clues?

```css
._inp {
  color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="_inp" value="10 x 30" />
</form>
```

Comment: I pasted the JSFiddle into a snippet and fixed your erroneous val=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS `word-spacing` property on the input field:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: since there are no spaces, there are no words, hence no word-spacing.

Comment: based on the input provided of "10 x 30" those would count as words, as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/f3zptxe6/

Answer (score 1):

Look this solution:

```js
var signsMap = new Map();
signsMap.set(16, "X");
signsMap.set(88, "x");
signsMap.set(107, "+");
signsMap.set(109, "-");
signsMap.set(111, "/");

var expression = document.getElementById("expression");
var numberSequence = false;

expression.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  console.log(!isNaN(e.key));
  if (signsMap.get(e.keyCode)) {
    findSign(signsMap.get(e.keyCode));
    numberSequence = false;
  } else if (!isNaN(e.key) && !numberSequence) {
    var expValue = expression.value;
    var head = expValue.substring(0, expression.selectionStart - 1);
    var body = expValue.substring(expression.selectionStart - 1, expression.selectionStart);
    var tail = expValue.substring(expression.selectionStart, expValue.length);
    expression.value = head + " " + body + tail;
    numberSequence = true;
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);

function findSign(sign) {
  var expValue = expression.value;
  if (sign) {
    if (expValue.indexOf(sign, expression.selectionStart - 1) > -1) {
      var head = expValue.substring(0, expression.selectionStart - 1);
      var body = expValue.substring(expression.selectionStart - 1, expression.selectionStart);
      var tail = expValue.substring(expression.selectionStart, expValue.length);
      expression.value = head + "   " + body + tail;
    }
  } else {
    for (const sign of signsMap.values()) {
      if (expValue.indexOf(sign) > -1) {
        expression.value = expValue.replace(sign, "   " + sign);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

window.onload = findSign(false);
```

```css
._inp {
  color: red;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="expression" class="_inp" value="10 x 30" />
</form>
```